# django modelform exclude fields that names math certain re

Tags: django, modelform

I want to exclude fields from a `modelform` that names contain a certain string `foo`. Example

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 400, unique=True)
    title_foo=models.BooleanField()
    ideas = models.ManyToManyField(Idea, through='StatusRelationship')
    ideas_foo=models.BooleanField()
    date_added=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I would like exclude the `title_foo` and `ideas_foo` without explicitly defining `exclude=['title_foo','ideas_foo']`in the form

Comment: why do you not want to exclude explicitly ?

Comment: I just don't want those ```foo``` fields to show up in the form

Comment: [field.name for field in Status._meta.fields if not 'foo' in field.name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of madzohan solved my question. `exclude=[field.name for field in Status._meta.fields if not 'foo' in field.name]`